# Is there a way to do a two step For loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, jupyter-notebook, astronomy

I am newer to Python so I'm not sure how I should edit my code to make it work. Basically, I am creating a bunch of URLs using the RA and DEC of different bright radio sources. An example of one of the URLs is: http://legacysurvey.org/viewer/cutout.jpg?ra=1.11804975451136&dec=37.55443630678226&layer=vlass1.2&pixscale=1.00
so the code I have right now is:

```
for x in bright_RA:
beginning_url = (url_start + x + url_middle)
for y in bright_DEC:
    full_url = (beginning_url + y + url_end)
    print(full_url)
```

where the bright_RA, bright_DEC, url_start, url_middle, and url_end are all strings. The problem I'm having is that I am only getting the first bright_RA value matched with all the bright_DEC values. Instead, I want each indice to match, where the 2nd value in bright_RA is printed with the 2nd value of bright_DEC and so on like that. 
Not sure how to make that happen.

Comment: You want `zip`?

Comment: You should first correct indentations as they change python code behaviour. Without them your code can't be even run.